# Como pasar los datos de un Jtable a otro Jtable

Tags: java

Cuando le doy doble click a la tabla de DATOS necesito que me envie los datos a sus respectivos lugares, lo que no logro hacer es que me envie el valor de ID AMA LLAVE Y NOM. AMA LLAVE a la tabla AMAS DE LLAVES ASIGNACIONES.
[image: IMAGEN DE LA FORMA EN JAVA]

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
//Acà capturo los datos de la tabla Tbl_Datos
            int idGobernanta = Integer.parseInt(Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
            int idPiso = Integer.parseInt(Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
            int idAmaDeLlave = Integer.parseInt(Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
            String nombreAmaDeLlave = (String) Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 4);

//Acà imprimo los datos que extraigo de la tabla Tbl_Datos
            Cbx_Gobernanta.setSelectedItem(idGobernanta);
            Cbx_Piso.setSelectedItem(idPiso);

            if (Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString().equals("Activo")) {
                Rdb_Activo.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                Rdb_Inactivo.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Logre solucionarlo, por si a alguien le llega a ser util.

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int idGobernanta = Integer.parseInt(Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
            int idPiso = Integer.parseInt(Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());

            Cbx_Gobernanta.setSelectedItem(idGobernanta);
            Cbx_Piso.setSelectedItem(idPiso);

            int filaSeleccionada = Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow();
            if (1 == 1) {
                if (filaSeleccionada >= 0) {
                    String Vector[] = new String[2];
                    Vector[0] = Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 3).toString();
                    Vector[1] = Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 4).toString();
                    modelo2.addRow(Vector);
                }
            }

            if (Tbl_Datos.getValueAt(Tbl_Datos.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString().equals("Activo")) {
                Rdb_Activo.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                Rdb_Inactivo.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).